refreshApex not working to display results from a wired backend call
I'm retrieving a list of time slots from salesforce and displaying them to choose from. The retrieval happens after a rental property is selected:
Before property selection:

After first time selection:

Select another property it finally works:

the issue I'm encountering is that the first time I select a property, nothing shows on the page even though I can see in the console that the time slots have been retrieved. Upon selection of another property, the time slots appear as expected. I'm trying to utilize refreshApex() to refresh the reactive property so that it will show on the page the first time but I can't get it to work.
I've tried to pass different parameters into refreshApex():
refreshApex(this.slots) as well as refreshApex(this.wiredSlots);
How can I get the time slots to refresh on the page the first time?
JS:
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getAvailableProperties from '@salesforce/apex/PropertyController.getAvailableProperties';
import getAvailableBookingSlots from '@salesforce/apex/PropertyController.getAvailableBookingSlots';
import createBooking from '@salesforce/apex/PropertyController.createBooking';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

export default class PropertyBooking extends LightningElement {
    @track selectedProperty;
    @track selectedSlot;
    @track error;
    @track slots = [];

    @wire(getAvailableProperties) properties;

    @wire(getAvailableBookingSlots, { propertyId: '$selectedProperty' })
    wiredSlots({ data, error }) {
        console.log('wiredSlots');
        console.log('this.selectedProperty --- ', this.selectedProperty);
        if (data) {
            //this.slots = data;
            for (let i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
                this.slots[i] = data[i].start + ' to ' + data[i].end;
            }
            console.log('this.slots ------- ', JSON.stringify(this.slots));
            this.error = undefined;
            return refreshApex(this.slots);
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.slots = [];
        }
    }

    get propertyOptions() {
        console.log('propertyOptions');
        return this.properties.data ? this.properties.data.map(property => {
            return { label: property.Name, value: property.Id };
        }) : [];
    }

    handlePropertyChange(event) {
        console.log('handlePropertyChange');
        this.selectedProperty = event.detail.value;
        this.selectedSlot = null; // Reset selected slot when changing property
    }
}

HTML:
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Property Booking" icon-name="custom:custom63">
        <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
            <template if:true={properties.data}>
                <lightning-combobox
                    name="property"
                    label="Select Property"
                    value={selectedProperty}
                    placeholder="Choose Property"
                    options={propertyOptions}
                    onchange={handlePropertyChange}
                    class="slds-m-bottom_small">
                </lightning-combobox>
            </template>
            <template if:true={selectedProperty}>                    
                    <p class="slds-text-title_bold">Available Booking Slots:</p>
                    <ul class="slds-m-bottom_medium">
                        <template for:each={slots} for:item="slot" for:index="index">
                            <li key={slot} class="slds-m-bottom_xx-small">
                                <lightning-button
                                    label={slot}
                                    value={slot}
                                    onclick={handleSlotSelection}
                                    data-slot={index}
                                    class="slds-button_brand">
                                </lightning-button>
                            </li>
                        </template>
                    </ul>
            </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>


You need to retain the original parameter to the wire handler to use refreshApex correctly. The data and error attributes don't contain the data you need to call refreshApex.
Here's an example:
#wireData;
wiredSlots(wireParams) {
  this.#wireData = wireParams;
}

The # just marks a field as private (inaccessible outside the class).
And when you want to refresh:
return refreshApex(this.#wireData);

Do not use refreshApex inside the wire handler, as this results in an infinite loop.
Instead, you can do this in the change handler, if necessary:
handlePropertyChange(event) {
    console.log('handlePropertyChange');
    this.selectedProperty = event.detail.value;
    this.selectedSlot = null; // Reset selected slot when changing property
    return refreshApex(this.#wireData);
}

That said, none of this is necessary. Wire handlers automatically update when they see a reactive property change. The following changes should work.
selectedProperty;
selectedSlot;

@wire(getAvailableProperties) properties;
@wire(getAvailableBookingSlots, { propertyId: '$selectedProperty' }) wiredSlots;

get propertyOptions() {
    console.log('propertyOptions');
    return this.properties.data ? this.properties.data.map(property => {
        return { label: property.Name, value: property.Id };
    }) : [];
}

get slots() {
    return this.#wireData.data;
}
get error() {
    return this.wiredSlots.error;
}

handlePropertyChange(event) {
    console.log('handlePropertyChange');
    this.selectedProperty = event.detail.value;
    this.selectedSlot = null; // Reset selected slot when changing property
}

